# SQLITE create table with UNIQUE column

Tags: php, sqlite, unique-constraint, unique-index

I am trying to create a table with an **UNIQUE** column in a PHP script but I get an error.

```
exec("sqlite3 /location/file.db 'CREATE TABLE $tablename (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,record_time_long UNIQUE VARCHAR(255),update_time_long UNIQUE VARCHAR(255),name VARCHAR(255),macaddress VARCHAR(255),longitude VARCHAR(255),latitude VARCHAR(255),sourcedevice VARCHAR(255),human_address VARCHAR(250),smce_hash VARCHAR(250),sm_hash VARCHAR(250),islowenergy VARCHAR(250),rssi INT(4));'");
```

When the script runs I get

```
SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: tablename in /location/script.php on line 41PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in /location/script.php:43
```

in the *error.log* of the *NGINX webserver*. So the table is not created. It works fine if I dont add the **UNIQUE** constraint after the column name.

I have also tried modifying my existing table right after the creation but I don't even get an error and the **UNIQUE** constraint is not added.

```
exec("sqlite3 /location/file.db 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX random_name ON $tablename(update_time_long);'");
```

Please help me, how can I make a column **UNIQUE** in my PHP script?

Comment: UNIQUE must be written after the data type: `record_time_long  VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE`. Also, there is no VARCHAR data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. Use TEXT.

Comment: I think there is VARCHAR but it is automatically treated as TEXT

Comment: @PrakharLondhe read the documentation in the link of my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you guys, it was so dumb simple -.-

Comment: @forpas I am speaking from the documentation itself, if you scroll some bit down, you can see it treats all the char, nvarchar, varchar as text.

Comment: @PrakharLondhe there is a difference between data type and affinity. If you define a column as VARCHAR it acquires TEXT affinity. This does not mean that there is a VARCHAR data type. You can define a column with `abc` data type (try it) although there is no `abc` data type.

Comment: Got it, not that familiar with sqlite.. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNIQUE` keyword should be added after the Column type, i.e varchar(255).

So change

`update_time_long UNIQUE VARCHAR(255)`

to

`update_time_long VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE`